# Why can't I call any methods in my code?

Tags: java, oop, generics

I'm trying to implement generics and OOP to data structures, but I'm running into a problem. When I try to test my code my instances aren't able to call any of the methods, here's what I have:

```
public class Queue<T> extends AbstractQueue<T> {
    // methods here
    @Override
    public Node<T> peek() { return head; }
}

public class QueueDemo {
    Queue<String> q = new Queue<String>();
    q.peek();
}
```

However my IDE throws the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'peek'
```

I'm sure I'm just missing something simple here, can anyone point it out? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are unrelated to the root problem.

You cannot invoke methods directly in the body of a class. The body of a class is meant to declare class members, not to contain executable behavior.

There are other issues here related to implementing the methods of `AbstractQueue`, but I'm going to assume you left that part of the code out.

Comment: ...Thanks... I completely forgot to make a main method, I need to go to bed.